# Transport polling error with Socket.Io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm getting a transport error when using socket.io v1.3.2. It's just meant to be a test for socket.io so I can familiarize myself with it.

I have a file `app.js` (taken directly from socket.io docs):

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(3000);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});
```

And a file `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Socket Test</h1>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the console, I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1422782880286-40 
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1422782880286-40. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
socket.io.js:3715 engine.io-client:socket socket error {"type":"TransportError","description":0} +37ms
socket.io.js:1402 socket.io-client:manager connect_error +38ms
socket.io.js:1402 socket.io-client:manager reconnect attempt error +1ms
socket.io.js:1402 socket.io-client:manager will wait 5000ms before reconnect attempt +0ms
socket.io.js:3715 engine.io-client:socket socket close with reason: "transport error" +2ms
socket.io.js:3715 engine.io-client:polling transport not open - deferring close +1ms
socket.io.js:1402 socket.io-client:manager attempting reconnect +5s
socket.io.js:1402 socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +0ms
socket.io.js:1402 socket.io-client:manager opening http://localhost +0ms
socket.io.js:3715 engine.io-client:socket creating transport "polling" +5s
socket.io.js:3715 engine.io-client:polling polling +0ms
socket.io.js:3715 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +0ms
socket.io.js:3715 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open GET: http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1422782885332-41 +1ms
socket.io.js:3715 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +0ms
socket.io.js:3715 engine.io-client:socket setting transport polling +1ms
socket.io.js:1402 socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +3ms
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error. I found [this discussion](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/issues/641), but have been unable to solve the problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The difference between your code and the sample on socket.io's site is that the socket.io example code is listening on port 80 and connecting the webSocket on port 80.  You are listening on port 3000, but trying to connect on port 80, thus the connection does not work.  `io.connect('http://localhost');` does not specify a port number so it will use the default http port which is port 80.  But, your websocket server is not listening on port 80 so the connection fails.

The simplest way to fix this is to change the line of code in the client from this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

to this:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

When you leave out the URL, it will, by default, use the domain and port from the current web page (which is what you want).

Answer (score 1):

by default, the localhost port is 80. you connected the client's socket to localhost without declaring the port. so it gave you the port 80 by default and your node server is listening to port 3000. in order for your client to connect to your server, you must declare the port which server listens. example: var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');